# Android stopping mediaplayer on activity leave/stop but not on orientation change

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-lifecycle

I am using MediaPlayer to play some sound in my app, I want this playback to stop when user leaves activity in which sound is being played.
So I did this by calling mediaplayer.stop() in my activities onStop() method.

```
public void onStop() {
 super.onDestroy();
 mediaPlayer.stop();
 mediaPlayer.reset();
}
```

but now when device rotation changes even then sound playback stops,because onStop() method is called, which I don't want, playback should continue when device orientation changes. How can this be done.

Comment: Does your manifest say you are handling orientation changes yourself?  If not, it is not just your MediaPlayer, but your entire Activity instance will be destroyed and then replaced.

Comment: For starters, I would suggest putting the `MediaPlayer` in a `Service` instead of the `Activity`. Bind to the `Service` from the `Activity` to control the `MediaPlayer` appropriately, and then work out how to handle orientation changes differently than the `Activity` stopping. Also, don't call `super.onDestroy()` from `onStop`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this ligne to your `Manifest.xml` inside the **`<Activity>`** you are focusing with that trouble :

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```